# Hdinsight pig default folder for UDF

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

just started using HDInsight.

I want to register an UDF in pig grunt mode but either thats not working or I don't know where to put the jar files in order for pig to load it.

right now what I did is to put the jar file in the lib folder (C:\apps\dist\pig-0.9.3-SNAPSHOT\lib) and in the pig root folder (C:\apps\dist\pig-0.9.3-SNAPSHOT) and nothing works for me , just keep getting this :

```
REGISTER elephant-bird-pig-3.0.0.jar;
```

and the response is :

2013-10-27 09:28:53,466 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 101: Local file 'elephant-bird-pig-3.0.0.jar' does not exist.
Details at logfile: C:\apps\dist\hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\logs\pig_1382864851131.log

please let me know where and how should I register this UDF.

Thank you

Comment: I succeeded in loading the UDFs by putting them in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put them in the BIN folder for long, because if the node gets reimaged you may lose the files. It is better to put them into Windows Azure storage.

1. Copy the extra .jar for your UDF onto Windows Azure Storage Blobs...  WASB.

   - You could make a "PigExtras" folder for example. Your source locations will vary, and your destination locations will be your container and account.
   - Upload via hadoop command line:

   `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\files\MyUDF.jar wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/MyUDF.jar`

   `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal c:\apps\dist\pig-0.11.0.1.3.1.0-06\piggybank.jar wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/piggybank.jar`

   - You can upload in other methods as well, such as:

     - Through .Net code such as http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#upload-blob
     - Through command line tools like AzCopy. Get it at https://github.com/downloads/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-downloads/AzCopy.zip
       AzCopy
2. Reference the .jar location in your Pig latin scripts. I believe a wildcard can be used to load all jars from a certain folder, but that may be inefficient if there are many in there.

   `REGISTER wasb:///PigExtras/*.jar;
   myset = load 'wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/data/file.txt' using MyUDF();
   dump myset`

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: We finally went with the last option , having a container with all the  UDFs which will always stay even when we purge the HDInsight server.
But I forgot about this question so thank you for your detailed answer.